# how to build game playing neural network in Python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, game-theory

I am a neural-network beginner.  I'd like to learn the basics of neural networks by teaching computers to play checkers.  Actually, the games I want to learn are [Domineering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domineering) and [Hex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_%28board_game%29).

These games are pretty easy to store and the rules are much simpler than chess, but there aren't too many people who play.  If I can get this idea off the ground it would be great for experimenting [Combinatorial Game Theory](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tom/Game_Theory/comb.pdf).

[PyBrain](http://pybrain.org/) seems to be the clear winner for Python neural networks, but who can walk me through how to set up a neural net for my game-playing task?  A google search turned up [Blondie24](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blondie24) in 2001 but it uses some genetic algorithms - I don't want to complicate things.

Comment: first you need to determine a heuristic on how to evaluate a gamestate

Comment: you might want to take this down. might be a massive influx of downvotes incoming

Comment: Neural networks actually aren't very good for exploring combinatorial game theory (and neither are genetic algorithms). The whole point of neural networks is that you can train them to find pattern-matching rules without ever knowing what those rules are. (Of course neural networks are very good for exploring how neural networks deal with combinatorial game theory, but that's not the same thing.)

Comment: okay... I should just replace "neural network" with "machine learning".

Comment: was thinking of this paper http://researcher.watson.ibm.com/researcher/files/us-beygel/samuel-checkers.pdf it uses something called "alpha-beta pruning".

Comment: @johnmangual: alpha-beta pruning is a good idea for game playing, but it has nothing to do whatsoever with machine learning.

Comment: What with posting an exact duplicate ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12593834/machine-learning-in-python-to-play-checkers

Answer (score 0):

Once you replace "neural networks" by *machine learning* (or even *artificial intelligence*, rather, imho) as the comments rightly suggest, I think you're better off starting with [Alpha-beta pruning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha-beta_pruning), the [Minimax algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimax), and [Branch and bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound) ideas.

Basically :

- At each step, you build the tree of all possible futures, and evaluate leaf positions with an *evaluation function* (e.g. board domination, connectivity, material, etc.)
- Propagate the results up in the tree, choosing the best play you can make, and the worse your opponent can (the best for him), until you know what move to play in the position you're at.
- Rinse, repeat. Branch and bound saves you a lot of computation if you have a few good heuristics, and the level of your programm will basically be how deep it'll be able to search the game tree.

This will most probably be the basic framework in which anyone would introduce new ideas, so if you're not familiar with it, go for it :-)

Comment: Learning the proper evaluation function is actually a pretty nice job for neural networks (or other supervised ML methods), trained on board positions with expected game outcomes.

Comment: @larsmans: Very nice answer for when he'll have rephrased the question, my own answer having become obsolete :)