# machine learning in Python to play checkers?

Tags: python, machine-learning, game-theory

I am a machine learning beginner.  I'd like to learn the basics by teaching computers to play checkers.  Actually, the games I want to learn are [Domineering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domineering) and [Hex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_%28board_game%29).  My language of choice is Python

These games are pretty easy to store and the rules are much simpler than chess, but there aren't too many people who play.  If I can get this idea off the ground it would be great for experimenting [Combinatorial Game Theory](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tom/Game_Theory/comb.pdf) to see if a computer and find the optimal move.

I found this old paper on checkers from the [1960's](http://researcher.watson.ibm.com/researcher/files/us-beygel/samuel-checkers.pdf) by a guy at IBM.  Originally I had asked about [neural networks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592857/how-to-build-game-playing-neural-network-in-python), but they are saying it's the wrong tool.

**EDIT**:  It could be that machine learning is not the right strategy.  In that case, what goes wrong? and what is a better way?

Comment: Why do you think that machine learning is a good approach for this problem?

Comment: I wanted to write something that "learns" how to play.  If they board is small enough, it may be possible to exhaustively search the space of moves.  What is a smarter way?

Comment: For classic checkers and many other games it is very difficult to calculate all possible moves. A possible alternative strategy is to define characteristics of strong positions or good moves and then try to find paths to those positions. For example, a strong position is where you vastly outnumber your opponent and a good move is to crown a soldier.

Comment: I would think Alpha/Beta would be better ai for this ...

Comment: If you're serious about learning about machine learning you'll want to explore many different approaches that a checkers alone might not allow you to explore. I've been following the Machine Learning course provided by Coursera taught by Andrew Ng. So far it's very good and it's free. I recommend you look into it.

Comment: Machine learning is actually a very interesting approach to this problem. I, for one, wasn't saying it's wrong, but you're asking too much in one question. I suggest you start by reading the first few chapters of [Russell & Norvig](http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu), who explain what the "guy at IBM" was doing quite lucidly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to build game playing neural network in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592857/how-to-build-game-playing-neural-network-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

You might want to take a look at the following: Chinook, Upper Confidence Trees, Reinforcement Learning, and Alpha-Beta pruning.  I personally like to combine Alpha-Beta Pruning and Upper Confidence Trees (UCT) for perfect information games where each player has less than 10 reasonable moves.  You can use Temporal Difference Learning to create a position evaluation function.  Game AI is probably the most fun way to learn machine learning.

For links to all of these topics, click on

http://artent.net/blog/2012/09/26/checkers-and-machine-learning/

(I was not able to include more links because the stack overflow software considers me a newbie!)

Answer (score 1):

Get the book called "Machine learning" by McGraw Hill and read the first chapter. It's extremely well written and the first chapter will teach you enough to make a program that plays checkers. Personally I made a program that plays 5 in a row on miniclip.com, also in python.

[http://www.amazon.com/Learning-McGraw-Hill-International-Editions-Computer/dp/0071154671](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071154671)

Comment: There must be several books called "Machine Learning".  Who is the author?

Comment: This comment is still relevant, part of chapter 1 is available online and it can give you some pointers. It specifically uses checkers as an example.

Answer (score 0):

When playing checkers, you seek to gain an advantage over your opponent by taking his or her pieces and crowning your own. Losing your pieces and allowing your opponent to crown his or her pieces is not desirable, so you avoid doing it.

Board game engines usually revolve around a position evaluation function. For checkers, my first guess would be something like this:

```
score =       number of allies         -     number of opponents
        + 3 * number of crowned allies - 3 * number of crowned opponents
```

Given a board, this function will return the score of the board. The higher the score, the better your position. The lower the score, the worse your position.

To make a naive checkers "engine", all you need to do is find the best move given a board position, which is just searching through all immediate legal moves and finding the one that maximizes your score.

Your engine won't think ahead more than one move, but it will be able to play against you somewhat.

The next step would to give your engine the ability to plan ahead, which essentially is predicting your opponent's responses. To do that, just find your opponent's best move (here comes recursion) and subtract it from your score.

Comment: yeah thats basically the start of alpha beta... nut you can look more than one move ahead ... it just takes a while ...